# Selenium how to click inside an md-sidenav

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

I have a web-page with an md-sidenav and I'm trying to test with selenium. Everything I do on the page works except when I try to click on elements inside the md-sidenav. When accessing web elements inside the md-sidenav with driver.findElement(By.name("elementName") or by id, I see that the element is not null. In addition, when accessing an , I can access all of its  sub-elements. But when I try to click on them, it gives me an ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element

Here is the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller='MyController as my' ng-cloak>
 <section layout="row" column>
    <md-sidenav id="sideNavRight" class="md-sidenav-right" md-component-id="right" ng-init="my.selectTab(1)">

    <div ng-controller="MyController" ng-show="my.isSelected(1)">
        <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Some Form</small>
            <md-button id="navClose" ng-click="close()" class="closeIcon"  aria-label="Close">
                <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/img/ic_close_white_24px.svg"></md-icon><sr-only>Close</sr-only>
            </md-button></h1>
        </md-toolbar>

        <md-content>
            <div layout="column" index="0">
            <h3>Some Information</h3> <br />
                <form name="myForm">
                    <div layout="row" layout-align="start" flex="100">
                        <md-input-container flex="">
                            <label>Category:</label>
                                <md-select name="category" required="" ng-model="menu.category" >
                                    <md-option class="choices" value="cat1">Category1</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="cat2">Category2</md-option>
                                    <md-option value="cat3">Category3</md-option>
                                </md-select>
                                <div class="errors" ng-messages="myForm.category.$error">
                                    <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
                                </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                        <div layout="row" class="pull-right">
                            <md-button class="btn" ng-click="clearValue()">Clear</md-button> &nbsp;
                            <md-button class="btn" ng-click="menu.updateCart();menu.selectTab(2);">Next</md-button>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </div>
    </md-sidenav>
  </section>

    ....
    rest of the page
    ....
</body>
```

And here is the Selenium code:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class EcsTest {
    static WebDriver driver;
    static Wait<WebDriver> wait;
    static String prevText = "";
    static String currText = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Dvp\\Irs\\EcsTest\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/ecs/index.html");

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("element1")).click();

            wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                    currText = webDriver.findElement(By.id("field1")).getText();
                    return !prevText.equals(currText);
                }
            });

            prevText = currText;

            driver.findElement(By.id("element2")).click();
            //driver.findElement(By.name("dispositionSelect")).sendKeys("Add to Scheme");

            Select selectElement = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("selectElement1")));
            disposition.selectByVisibleText("Some form");

            WebElement sideNav = driver.findElement(By.id("sideNavRight"));
            WebElement closeBtn = sideNav.findElement(By.id("navClose"));

            /*
                This prints out:
                sideNav is not null!, closeBtn is not null!, not displayed!, enabled!
            */
            System.out.println(
                    "sideNav is " + ((sideNav == null) ? "null!" : "not null!") +
                    ", closeBtn is " + ((closeBtn == null) ? "null!" : "not null!") +
                    ", " + ((closeBtn.isDisplayed()) ? "displayed!" : "not displayed!") +
                    ", " + ((closeBtn.isEnabled()) ? "enabled!" : "not enabled!"));


            WebElement select = sideNav.findElement(By.name("category"));
            List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("md-option"));

            /*
                This prints out:
                select: category, visible: false
            */
            System.out.println(
                "select: " + select.getAttribute("name") + ", visible: " + select.isDisplayed());

            /*
                This crashes:
                ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element

                Without this click, I can see the options fine but the option click crashes
            */
            select.click();

            for(WebElement option : options) {
                System.out.println("option: " + option.getAttribute("value"));

                if(option.getAttribute("value").equals(optionName)) {
                    option.click();
                    System.out.println("option: " + option.getAttribute("value") + " clicked!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            driver.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some suggested checks. (1) try another browser, MSIE driver is known to be flaky - especially with Actions, so try your answer in Chrome? (2) try a wait of 10 sec between opening the side nav and clicking in it. (3) add more debug output - is sideNav visible? (4) try clicking the `<md-icon>` element under your close button element.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some wait for the said element to be visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(select));

select.click();
```

If you are still not able to click the element then try using `Actions class` as mentioned in the one of the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Actions class:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
```

And use it for every operation as long as you're in the md-sidenav:

```
WebElement yourElement = sideNav.findElement(By.id("elementId"));
builder.moveToElement(yourElement).click().build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(yourElement).sendKeys("2017-05-04").build().perform();
```

Etc.

Edit:
This only causes the operations not to throw and exception but it doesn't actually perform the operation. I.e. it reports that it clicked a button, no exception was thrown but no action was taken either.
I was too quick to be happy.